# Compressing file to Zip file using PclZip on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, compression, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to compress txt file to a zip file stored on a google cloud storage bucket.

I've written a function below which works on local files but not on files stored on the cloud bucket.

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
  $archive = new PclZip("gs://.../file.zip");
  $v_list = $archive->add("gs://.../file.txt");

  if ($v_list == 0) {
    die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
  }
```

I want the zip file to be saved in the same directory in my Google storage bucket

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Could you share the error message you got when writing to GCS?

Comment: @Mars Warning: php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons. It can be re-enabled by adding it to the google_app_engine.enable_functions ini variable in your applications php.ini in /base/data/home/apps/s~melodic-bazaar-621/1.376845490841881981/pclzip.lib.php on line 5679 Error : PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : File 'gs://.../file.txt' does not exist

Comment: I assume you do have 'gs://.../file.txt' in your GCS already? In any case, doing zip file this way is probably not very efficient given the number of GCS read/write involved. If you can fit everything in memory, you'd want to use php://temp during the construction and only write out to GCS at the very end.